# How to test the IBM WebSphere Message Broker in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jms

I have a scenario where i need to test the IBM WebSphere Message Broker(JMS request) in JMeter.

Currently i have below details with me. Using this below information, may i know how to create this script in JMeter.

Example :
Queue manager name : ACE config SVR/TCP/localhost(1414),
Queue name : DNB LT.SRVC,
XML Payload

Also, Manual testing team is using the RHF utility to perform this testing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best option is going for [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and custom Groovy code.

1. Download the relevant version of [com.ibm.mq.allclient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient) and drop it to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation (or other location which is in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath))
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Add JSR223 Sampler to your Test plan
4. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConnectionFactory
   import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory
   import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants

   import javax.jms.Session

   def hostName = "127.0.0.1"
   def hostPort = 1414
   def channelName = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN"
   def queueManagerName = "QM1"
   def queueName = "DNB LT.SRVC"

   def ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER)
   def cf = ff.createConnectionFactory()

   cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, hostName)
   cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, hostPort)
   cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, channelName)
   cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT)
   cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, queueManagerName)

   def conn = cf.createConnection("app", "test")
   def sess = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)

   def destination = sess.createQueue(queueName)

   conn.start()

   def producer = sess.createProducer(destination)

   def payload = 'Your XML payload here'
   def msg = sess.createTextMessage(payload)

   producer.send(msg)

   producer.close()

   conn.close()
   sess.close()
   ```
5. Run your test and the message should be sent

More information: [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. I will create my script as you mentioned above.